# If this answer is not low quality then what is it?

Tags: discussion, answers, flagging

[This](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/11068/10202) answer was a one-line answer when posted, I replied on a comment mentioning how the answer didn't actually solved my problem and I explained why. User proceeded to edit his answer and in reality it was a really poor edit as in:

1. It didn't elaborate on the main idea of the answer
2. Added another solution (which is not encouraged on the site, different answers should be posted as individual answers)
3. New solution was based on an assumption

I let OP know that the edit is bad and pointless cause he's assuming things about the question's OP (since assumptions deviate original intent). I proceeded to downvote the answer and flag it as very-low-quality, flag which was declined under the reason of:

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

Which it's somewhat odd, considering a mod included this message for OP

> We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

So I'm left with a huge question mark on top of my head. If this answer shouldn't have been flagged as very-low-quality then how should have I flagged it as?

Comment: I'm grateful for your commitment to quality. That's very important. It's reflected in all your posts too. Leadin' by example :)

Comment: Well I also think my example could be more exemplary but I'm trying to be a better contributor in LH @J.Musser I'm not angry about the outcome of the flag just want to get the right answer in case I happen to be in the same situation again

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That answer is low quality. But here's the point. This site is based on the idea that the more user-based it is, the better. We want the site to be running smoothly with as little moderation as possible (outside of what moderation is available to any user as they unlock privileges). **The Low Quality Posts review queue is designed for the community to take care of these answers on its own.**

In the case of the answer you mentioned, as you [noted in a comment](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/11046/how-do-i-make-my-room-or-even-an-apartment-warmer-cozier/11068#comment15944_11068), this was a valid answer, but could be considered wrong. **Save the flags for severe formatting issues, incomprehensibility, and severe content problems** (also note that abusive/spam posts should be flagged as such - heavier flag penalties).

In this case, you can **downvote** the answer, and it will likely end up in the Low Quality review queue, and the community (not the moderators) can decide whether or not to click delete. Remember, we want the community to be as nearly self - moderating as possible.

Although a user without sufficient reputation to delete vote a downvoted answer *can* flag an answer lq to get it into the review, that flag will be subject to the judgement of a moderator who must determine whether or not the flag actually does require moderator intervention.

On another note, it's always good to try and be nice. We want to build up a good user base here, and one of the best means is to treat new users well, and make them feel valued. Everyone new will have a lot to learn. Be nice in commenting, and other dealings with (especially new) users.

Also see [**What does the “very low quality” flag mean in regards to answers?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122443/what-does-the-very-low-quality-flag-mean-in-regards-to-answers/122447#122447)

Comment: Well this makes a lot of sense, I always thought that in order for a post to be in the LQ queue I had to flag it as such

Answer (score 5):

*Note: I'm not the mod who handled that flag; I notified them of this post.*

Because the answer is fixable, we won't delete it. Like the very low quality flag says, it should be used for q/a "unlikely to be salvageable through editing".

It's better that we encourage the author to either improve their post. To let them know their post needs some work we can leave a comment and downvote as needed.

They may choose to just delete the post, but in that case the author is still learning what is and what isn't good for the site.